# Cloudkit JS - Query Records by the user that created them

Tags: javascript, metadata, cloudkit

I'm trying to use a query with CloudKit JS, and because I'm looking specifically in the public database, I would like to query only the records from a particular user.

Now with the perform query, I know that you can query records based on their record name like so:

```
  var Query = {
      recordType: 'Animals',
      filterBy: [{systemFieldName: 'recordName', comparator: 'EQUALS', fieldValue: {value:{recordName: "_964c2fe93480jd209485hcgm5"}}}],  
      sortBy: [{fieldName: 'animal_Name'}]
    };
```

I want to know if it is possible to query the records using the userRecordName found in created and modified objects when records are returned?

I have selected Query under the "createdBy" metadata field for this record type, but have no clue how to query it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can query by the user. Below is a sample, where `recordA` is a ID of user recorder.

```
"query": {
"recordType": "Animals",
"filterBy": [
  {
    "systemFieldName": "createdUserRecordName",
    "comparator": "EQUALS",
    "fieldValue": {
      "value": {
        "recordName": "recordA",
      },
      "type": "REFERENCE"
    }
  }
],
```